# Implement boolean indexing with Tensorflow Tensors and assign a new value to those indices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm developing an algorithm that uses a CNN network, Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Python 3.7.7.

I'm trying to do this, that I've done it with Numpy...

```
# output_np is a Numpy Array.
output_np[output_np >= 0.5] = 1.0
```

...with Tensors... but I can't, because the same code with a Tensor throws this error:

```
'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

So, I have tried to implement boolean indexing in another way. I have tried this code to find a way to do it:

```
r2 = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dtype=tf.float16)

r2_1 = r2[r2 > 4]
print(r2_1)
# Output:
#    tf.Tensor([5. 6.], shape=(2,), dtype=float16)

r2_2 = tf.where(r2 > 4)
print(r2_2)
# Output:
#    tf.Tensor(
#       [[2 0]
#        [2 1]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int64)

indices = r2 > 4
print(indices)
# Output
#   tf.Tensor(
#       [[False False]
#        [False False]
#        [ True  True]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=bool)

r2[indices] = 0
# Error:
#    only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

r2[1] = 0
# Error:
#    'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

It seems that `indices = r2 > 4` is the way to do it, but I don't know how to assign a new value to a Tensor because it throws two errors.

I've thought to create a new Tensor with the new values at `indices`, and for the rest, the same values as r2, but I don't know how to do it. And also, because I'm using this Tensor into my own loss function, and then on a gradient function, I don't want to interrupt the gradient chain registered by the gradient tape.

```
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
        loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)

    return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

What can I do to end my implementation?

**UPDATE**:

I have tried this code:

```
r2 = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(r2, 4), 0, r2)
print(r2)
# Output:
#   tf.Tensor(
#       [[1. 2.]
#        [3. 0.]
#        [0. 0.]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float16)

r3 = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]], dtype=tf.float16)
print(r3)
# Output:
#   tf.Tensor(
#       [[0.1 0.2]
#        [0.3 0.4]
#        [0.5 0.6]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float16)

r3 = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(r2, 0.5), 1, r3)
r3 = tf.where(tf.less(r2, 0.5), 0, r3)
print(r3)
# Output:
#   tf.Tensor(
#       [[1. 1.]
#        [1. 0.]
#        [0. 0.]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float16)
```

This is what I have to do: **round values equal or greater of 0.5 to 1, and to 0 values less than 0.5**.

```
r3 = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(r2, 0.5), 1, r3)
r3 = tf.where(tf.less(r2, 0.5), 0, r3)
```

And the output should be:

```
tf.Tensor(
    [[0. 0.]
     [0. 0.]
     [1. 1.]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float16)
```

But it is:

```
tf.Tensor(
    [[1. 1.]
     [1. 0.]
     [0. 0.]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float16)
```

Comment: Can't you use [`tf.math.round`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/round) for this? (and if values can go beyond the interval [0, 1] just use [`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value) later)

Comment: In your last snippet, `r3 = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(r2, 0.5), 1, r3)`, and `r3 = tf.where(tf.less(r2, 0.5), 0, r3)`, did you mean to use `r3` as argument to `tf.greater_equal` and `tf.less`? In any case, you could reduce that to `r3 = tf.where(r3 >= 0.5, tf.ones_like(r3), tf.zeros_like(r3))`.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I have tried `tf.round`, and it does what I want. Thanks.